# Nested Floating Divs

Tags: html

I have two MAIN DIVs inside a DIV which is a PART of the page.

```
<div class="commentholder">                                     
<div class="cthumbnail"> <!-- #1 -->
    <a href="#"><img src="source"></a>
</div>

<div class="ccontent"> <!-- #2 -->
    <a href="#" class="post_author">Dilip Raj Baral</a>

    this is a comment..

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="cstatus">
        April 16, 2012 &#183;
        <a href="#" class="like">Like</a> &#183;
        <a href="#" class="likes">0</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

As shown CTHUMBNAIL and CCONTENT are two main DIVs inside a DIV. They are actually two columns. CTHUMBNAIL has a THUMBNAIL of a picture to display at the left and CCONTENT has comments. CSS associated with them are:

```
#content .commentholder {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    border: 2px dotted #d2d9e7; /**********/
    }
#content .ccontent {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 350px; /*change*/
#content .cstatus {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1px;
    color: #979797;
    font-size: 11px;
    }
#content .cthumbnial {float: left;} 
#content .cthumbnail img {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    }
```

http://connectu.saipal.edu.np/styles/style.cssThis is the **FULL CSS** if you require..

COMMENTHOLDER div should be bordered with the floating DIVs THUMBNAIL and CCONTENT inisde it. But it doesn't happen so. Rather, it displays like:

http://minus.com/mCCHNGVfu/ (this is the image link. i wasnt' allowed to include an image.

Thumbnail and Comment are not inside the border of COMMENTHOLDER DIV.

This is what I was trying to fix the whole day.

What must be the glitch.. help me out, please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below code,`height:100%; overflow:hidden` these two property allows the element to stretch heightwise. Whenever you use floating divs just add these two property to the parent element.

```
#content .commentholder {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    border: 2px dotted #d2d9e7; /**********/
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added a float:left; to your .ccontent div but you didn't clear the float.. 
Add a div with your class='clear' after the .ccontent and see if the problem goes away.Also you can try solution in this [link](http://www.mikepadgett.com/technology/technical/solution-to-nested-div-float-problems/).